# how to get common substring in two string to maintain order?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do one problem of `hackerrank` but I am not able to solve that problem

Can someone please help me with wrong logic implementation done by me?

problem

**Print the length of the longest string, such that  is a child of both  s1 and s2.**

Sample Input

```
HARRY
SALLY
```

Sample Output

```
 2
```

Explanation

The longest string that can be formed by deleting zero or more characters from  HARRY and SALLY is AY, whose length is 2.

Sample Input 1

```
AA
BB
```

Sample Output 1

```
0
```

Explanation 1

AA and BB have no characters in common and hence the output is 0

Sample Input 2

```
SHINCHAN
NOHARAAA
```

Sample Output 2

```
3
```

Explanation 2

The longest string that can be formed between  SHINCHAN and NOHARAAA  while maintaining the order is NHA.

I have written some logic which is as follows:

```js
 

   function commonChild(s1, s2) {

    var arr = s2.split(),
        currenString = '',
        maxLength = 0,
        index = -1;
  console.log(arr);

    for (var i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        var char = s1.charAt(i),
            charIndex = arr.indexOf(char);
        console.log(char)
        if (index < charIndex) {
            index = charIndex;
            currenString +=char;
        }

        maxLength= Math.max(maxLength,currenString.length)
    }

    return maxLength;

}


commonChild('ABCDEF', 'FBDAMN');


console.log(commonChild('ABCDEF', 'FBDAMN'));
```

Comment: if `s2` does not contain the character, you set your loop index `i` to `-1`, from which it will never recover. Next time, post what is not working about your code, and don't just paste some infinite-loop code without any comment.

Comment: see the update of questions

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the problem you are having with your code? Do you get an error message? If yes, what does it say and what line does it occur on? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? If yes, what result do you expect and why do you expect that result, what result do you get and why is that result not the correct one? Is the behavior you are observing not the behavior you are expecting? If yes, what behavior do you expect and why do you expect that behavior, what behavior do you observe instead and why is that behavior not the correct one?

Comment: Your edit does not help with the main problem of this question, which is that this question does not contain a question! What *is* your exact question? You have posted an exercise problem, and you have posted code which solves that exercise problem. Ergo, the problem is solved. Or is it not? Obviously, the problem is *not* solved, otherwise you wouldn't have posted this question, but *why* did you post this question? What is wrong with your code? We cannot help you if you don't tell us *what* we should help you with. Please, read, understand, and apply [ask] and how to construct a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your code before the edit.
One little change is to change `var arr = s2.split()` to `split('')`.
The main change in the logic is that I added a loop to run over the string each time from another character (first loop from the first, second from the second etc).

```js
function commonChild(s1, s2) {
  var arr = s2.split(''),
    currenString = '',
    maxLength = 0,
    index = -1,
    j = -1;
  for (var ii = 0; ii < s1.length; ii++) {
    index = -1;
    currenString = '';
    for (var i = ii; i < s1.length; i++) {
      var char = s1.charAt(i),
        j = arr.indexOf(char);
      if (index < j) {
        index = j;
        currenString += char;
      }
      maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, currenString.length)
    }
  }
  return maxLength;
}
console.log(commonChild('ABCDEF', 'FBDAMN'));
```

Comment: `commonChild("ABCDE", "BCDEA");` expected: 4, got: 3

Answer (score 1):

pardon me. this is an unoptimized solution.

```js
function maxCommon(a, b, offset) {
  offset = offset || 0;

  if (a === b) {
    return [[a, b]];
  }
  var possibleSolns = [];
  for (var i = 0 + offset; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0 + offset; j < b.length; j++) {
      if (a.charAt(i) === b.charAt(j)) {
        possibleSolns.push([
          a.substring(0, offset) + a.substring(i),
          b.substring(0, offset) +b.substring(j)
        ]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  var results = [];
  possibleSolns.forEach(function(soln) {
    var s = maxCommon(soln[0], soln[1], offset+1);
    if (s.length === 0) {
      s = [[soln[0].substring(0, offset +1), soln[1].substring(0, offset +1)]];
    }
    results = results.concat(s);
  });
  return results;
}

var maxLen = -1;
var soln = null;
maxCommon("ABCDEF", "FBDAMN").map(function(_) {
  return _[0];
}).forEach(function(_) {
  if (_.length > maxLen) {
    soln = _;
    maxLen = _.length;
  }
});

console.log(soln);
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept most of your logic in the answer:

```js
function commonChild(s1, s2) {
  var // Sets strings to arrays
    arrayString1 = s1.split(""),
    arrayString2 = s2.split(""),
    collectedChars = "",
    maxLength = 0,
    max = arrayString1.length;
  

  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    var
      char = arrayString1[i],
      count = arrayString2.indexOf(char);
     
    // check if char is in second string and not in collected
    if (count != -1 && collectedChars.indexOf(char) == -1) {
      collectedChars += char;
      maxLength++;
    }
  }

  return maxLength;
}

// expected output 4
console.log(commonChild(
                'ABCDEF',
                'FBDAMN'
            ));

// expected output 1
console.log(commonChild(
                'AA',
                'FBDAMN'
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash and spread operation you can do it in this way.

```
const test = (first, second) => {
  const stringArray1 = [...first];
  const stringArray2 = [...second];
  return _.intersection(stringArray1, stringArray2).length;
}

console.log(test('ABCDEF', 'FBDAMN'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using lcs least common subsequence

```
function LCS(s1,s2,x,y){
    var result = 0;
    if(x==0 || y==0){
        result = 0
    }else if(s1[x-1] == s2[y-1]){
        result = 1+ LCS(s1,s2,x-1,y-1)
    } else if(s1[x-1] != s2[y-1]){
        result = Math.max(LCS(s1,s2,x-1,y), LCS(s1,s2,x,y-1))
    }
    return result;
}



// Complete the commonChild function below.
function commonChild(s1, s2) {

    return LCS(s1,s2,s1.length,s2.length);

}
```